# PHP Move DOMDocument nodes to a new parent

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have a xml file from a client which is not compleet what i want, so i have to rewrite it.

This is what i have:

```
<artikel>
    <kop>
        <titel>Artikel 2.</titel>
    </kop>

    <lid>
        <lidnr>1</lidnr>
        <al>content</al>
    </lid>

    <lid>
        <lidnr>2</lidnr>
        <al>content</al>
    </lid>

</artikel>
```

and this is what i need:

```
<artikel>
    <kop>
        <titel>Artikel 2.</titel>
    </kop>

    <leden>
        <lid>
            <lidnr>1</lidnr>
            <al>content</al>
        </lid>

        <lid>
            <lidnr>2</lidnr>
            <al>content</al>
        </lid>
    </leden>
</artikel>
```

I do not know xml very well, so i have a problem. I think this needed to be done:

1) create a new_parent_node "leden"
2) per "lid": add "lid" to "leden" node and remove from "artikel" node
3) add new node "leden" after "kop" node

This is what i have so far:

```
$dom->load($publicatieurl_xml);

$artikels = $dom->getElementsByTagName('artikel');            

foreach ($artikels as $key => $artikel) {

    $lidNodes = $artikel->getElementsByTagName('lid');
    if ( $lidNodes->length !== 0 ) {
        $new_parent_node = $dom->createElement('leden');
        foreach ( $lidNodes as $key => $lid ) {
            $new_parent_node->appendChild( $lid );
        }
        echo ($new_parent_node->ownerDocument->saveXML($new_parent_node));
    }                
}
```

Where this does not work: $new_parent_node->appendChild( $lid );
because it is an object.

So what i need to know is:

1) how can i add the already existing XML-element "$lid" to my "leden" node
2) how do i remove the "lid" nodes? Yet another foreach loop? Because i can not remove it in the one where i append the $lid, because that ruins the foreach elements...

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`XSLT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) for that. First create the stylesheet document:

*translate.xsl*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <artikel>
      <xsl:copy-of select="/artikel/kop" />
      <leden>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/artikel/lid" />
      </leden>
    </artikel>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now comes the PHP code:

```
// Load input from customer. (Can be an http:// url if desired)
$input = new DOMDocument();
$input->load('input.xml');

// Load the stylesheet document
$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load('translate.xsl');

$xsltproc = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsltproc->importStylesheet($xsl);

// transformToXML() returns the translated xml as a string
echo $xsltproc->transformToXML($input);

// ... or transformToDoc() can be used if you need to
// further process the translated xml.
$newdoc = $xsltproc->transformToDoc($input);
```

---

Btw, if you don't want to store the xsl in a separate file, you use `DOMDocument::loadXML()` to load it:

```
$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->loadXML(<<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <artikel>
      <xsl:copy-of select="/artikel/kop" />
      <leden>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/artikel/lid" />
      </leden>
    </artikel>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOF
);
```